# The size for values of type `dyn Dog` cannot be known at compilation time and other std::marker::Sized shenanigans

Tags: rust, traits

Code-related explanation is put in the code itself in the form of comments.

```rust
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

fn random_number(start: u32, end_exclusive: u32) -> u32 {
     // Just some random-number generation code..
}

//This is where the problem starts..
//VVVVVVVVV
trait Dog 
/* Error from compiler:
--------- doesn't satisfy `dyn Dog: std::marker::Sized`
*/
{
    fn eat(&self, food: u8);
    fn sleep(&self, hours: u8);
}

struct PetDog {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

impl Dog for PetDog {
    fn eat(&self, food: u8) {
        println!("{} ate {} food items but fat chonker is still hungry!", self.name, food);
    }
    fn sleep(&self, hours: u8) {
     // Just some boring piece of code that determines 
     // if the sleep hours were healthy according 
     // to the age of the doggo and prints that conclusion to screen.
    }    
}

struct StreetDog {
    age: u8,
}

impl StreetDog {
    // This is a dodgy/hacky workaround for getting an ID for a StreetDog
    // (since they don't have names)
    // My intention was to get their memory address and use it as an ID.
    // Left because it may also be the source of some bugs!
    fn get_id(&self) -> u32 {
        let id: *const Self = &*self;
        id as u32
    }
}

impl Dog for StreetDog {
    fn eat(&self, food: u8) {
        let id = self.get_id();
        println!("Lucky Dog #{} got to eat {} food items and it's thankful.", id, food);
    }
    fn sleep(&self, hours: u8) {
        // Almost same boring code.
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dogs: [dyn Dog; 4] =
/*            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time 
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Dog`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: slice and array elements must have `Sized` type
*/
    [
        PetDog { name: String::from("Rufus"), age: 10},
/*      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Dog`, found struct `PetDog`
   = note: expected trait object `dyn Dog`
                    found struct `PetDog`

*/
        StreetDog {age: 17},
        PetDog { name: String::from("Nebula"), age: 14},
        StreetDog {age: 7},
    ];

    for dog in dogs.iter() {
/*                  ^^^^ method not found in `[dyn Dog; 4]`
   = note: the method `iter` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn Dog: std::marker::Sized`
*/
        dog.eat(random_number(1, 6));
        dog.sleep(random_number(4, 13));
    }
}
```

The errors:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Dog` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/structs_traits_impl.rs:90:15
   |
90 |     let dogs: [dyn Dog; 4] = [
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Dog`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: slice and array elements must have `Sized` type

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/structs_traits_impl.rs:91:9
   |
91 |         PetDog { name: String::from("Rufus"), age: 10},
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Dog`, found struct `PetDog`
   |
   = note: expected trait object `dyn Dog`
                    found struct `PetDog`

error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for array `[dyn Dog; 4]` in the current scope
  --> src/structs_traits_impl.rs:97:21
   |
17 | trait Dog {
   | --------- doesn't satisfy `dyn Dog: std::marker::Sized`
...
97 |     for dog in dogs.iter() {
   |                     ^^^^ method not found in `[dyn Dog; 4]`
   |
   = note: the method `iter` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn Dog: std::marker::Sized`
```

This `std::marker::Sized` error has bugged me for the past 2 days and I couldn't find a proper solution anywhere here or at other forums/documentation.

Comment: The duplicates [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7cf6ae2f28cbe772c2dadb45d08cdf84)

Comment: Use a `dyn Box<Dog>` or a `&dyn Dog`