# Storing objects of any type in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits

I want to implement a class `Storage` that can store objects of any types. I am trying to do that using `trait Any`. The `Storage::insert::<T>(key, value)` should add a pair, where the key is always some `String` type, and the value can be any type. When I store a `Box<HashMap<String, dyn Any>>` the compiler says that it doesn't have size at compile-time. So how can I avoid that error ?

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::hash_map::Keys;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Storage where Self: Sized{
    map: Box<HashMap<String, dyn Any>>,
}

impl Storage {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            map: Some(Box::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert<Q: Any>(&mut self, key: &dyn Any, obj: Q) {
        if key.is::<String>() {
            let key_string = key.downcast_ref::<String>().unwrap();
            self.map.as_mut().insert(key_string.clone(), obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'm not sure that such class can be implemented with `std::collections::HashMap`

Comment: You need to wrap the dyn YourTrait with Box not the whole Hashmap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects)

Comment: There are bunch of other duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475692/the-size-for-values-of-type-dyn-dog-cannot-be-known-at-compilation-time-and-ot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `HaspMap<K, V>` needs to have `Sized` types `K` and `V`, which is not the case of `dyn Any`. This means that the size of `K` and `V` must be known at compile time. For instance, you always know that an `u32` will take 32 bits, but the size of `[u32]` is not known beforehand. Therefore: `u32: Sized`, and `[u32]: !Sized`.

This is also the case of `dyn Any`, `dyn Any: !Sized`, because objects of different size can implement `Any`, and, in fact, *every* object implements `Any`.

To solve this, there is an easy patch, and it's wrapping that type with `Box<_>`. `Box` is a pointer to a heap-allocated memory, so you know its size will always be the size of a pointer (roughly speaking), and you don't need to know at compile time how much memory you will allocate on the heap. Here it goes:

```rust
pub struct Storage {
  map: Box<HashMap<String, Box<dyn Any>>>,
}
```

You will also have to adapt the rest of the code, but you can find everything [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html).

Comment: I seem to understand. Your answer gave me a lot of insight. Previously I have implemented a class using Box<dyn Any> and now I understand why it worked there and doesn't work here with Box<HashMap>. Thanks a lot!