# "the size for values of type cannot be known at compilation time" when trying to return vector of dyn Traits from function

Tags: rust

I have a function `Processor::process` which can return dynamic vector of functions. When I try to use it I got an error:

> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn FnMut(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

This is my code:

```
fn handler1(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

fn handler2(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

fn handler3(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

struct Processor {}
impl Processor {
    pub fn process(data: u8) -> Vec<dyn FnMut(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8>> {
        return match data {
            1 => vec![handler1],
            2 => vec![handler1, handler2],
            3 => vec![handler1, handler2, handler3],
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

This is [minimal sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=381c6d14660d47beaece15d068b3dc6a).

Could you please help to set correct typing for function return?

Comment: Are you certain you need `dyn FnMut(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8>` and not only `fn(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8>`? Functions don't have any captured environment (as opposed to closures) then their size is known at compile time. The alternative would be to use `Box<dyn FnMut(...>` but in this case there is a dynamic allocation and one more indirection.

Comment: @prog-fh thanks for asking! in example above I do not need. It's just a sample code. In my real code I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects)

Comment: Also [The size for values of type `dyn Dog` cannot be known at compilation time and other std::marker::Sized shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475692/the-size-for-values-of-type-dyn-dog-cannot-be-known-at-compilation-time-and-ot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you **box** them, or you return a **reference** with an specific lifetime. In this case 'static:

```rust
fn handler1(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

fn handler2(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

fn handler3(a: String, b: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8> {
    None
}

struct Processor {}
impl Processor {
    pub fn process(data: u8) -> Vec<&'static dyn FnMut(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8>> {
        return match data {
            1 => vec![&handler1],
            2 => vec![&handler1, &handler2],
            3 => vec![&handler1, &handler2, &handler3],
            _ => vec![]
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28ea1506b01d10b1d97287002441b73f)

You can also just use function pointers instead of the trait dynamic dispatch:

```rust
impl Processor {
    pub fn process(data: u8) -> Vec<fn(String, Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Option<u8>> {
        return match data {
            1 => vec![handler1],
            2 => vec![handler1, handler2],
            3 => vec![handler1, handler2, handler3],
            _ => vec![]
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6af88a9b1be09d77a795e9923c724a3d)

Comment: could you please explain why static ref helps in this case ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo, because functions lives for the entire of the program. So you can statically reference them. It doesn't happen with closures for example.